# Creating a JSON Array by inserting all the data coming from a loop using spring boot

Tags: arrays, json, spring-boot

I have implemented a code to import data from a .pcap file. It works correctly. It reads the cap files and in the console displays the results.

The code for this is,

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class SpringBootSecurityJwtMongodbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSecurityJwtMongodbApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(FTPConfiguration.GateFile gateFile) {
        return args -> {
            List<File> files = gateFile.mget(".");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.println("Result:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
                run(file);
            }
        };
    }

    void run(File file) throws IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        Pcap pcap = Pcap.openStream(file);
        pcap.loop(
                packet -> {
                    if (packet.hasProtocol(Protocol.TCP)) {
                        TCPPacket packet1 = (TCPPacket) packet.getPacket(Protocol.TCP);
                        String Time = formatter.format(new Date(packet1.getArrivalTime() / 1000));
                        String Source = packet1.getSourceIP();
                        String Destination = packet1.getDestinationIP();
                        String Protocol = packet1.getProtocol().toString();
                        Long Length = packet1.getTotalLength();
                        System.out.printf("%s | %s | %s | %s | %d \n", Time, Source, Destination, Protocol, Length);
                       } else if (packet.hasProtocol(Protocol.UDP)) {
                        UDPPacket packet1 = (UDPPacket) packet.getPacket(Protocol.UDP);
                        String Time = formatter.format(new Date(packet1.getArrivalTime() / 1000));
                        String Source = packet1.getSourceIP();
                        String Destination = packet1.getDestinationIP();
                        String Protocol = packet1.getProtocol().toString();
                        Long Length = packet1.getTotalLength();
                        System.out.printf("%s | %s | %s | %s | %d \n", Time, Source, Destination, Protocol, Length);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Not found protocol. | " + packet.getProtocol());
                    }
                   return packet.getNextPacket() != null;
                }
        );
    }
}
```

I want to get these data into a JSON Array. So that the output should be like the following.

```
[
  {"Destination":"116.50.76.245","Length":119,"Time":"03:41:08","Protocol":"udp","Source":"4.2.2.2"},
  {"Destination":"10.64.33.73","Length":92,"Time":"03:41:06","Protocol":"tcp","Source":"91.198.174.192"},
  {"Destination":"4.2.2.2","Length":74,"Time":"03:41:08","Protocol":"udp","Source":"10.64.43.166"},
  {"Destination":"4.2.2.2","Length":74,"Time":"03:41:08","Protocol":"udp","Source":"10.64.43.166"}
]
```

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an instance of `JSONArray` and pass it to `run` method, and create an instance of `JSONObject` inside `packet -> {}` method body, and populate and push the `JSONObject` to passed instance of `JSONArray`. Below is the minimal code:

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(FTPConfiguration.GateFile gateFile) {
    ...
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    for (File file : files) {
        System.out.println("Result:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        run(file, arr);
    }
    ...
}

void run(File file, JSONArray arr) throws IOException {
    ...
        packet -> {
            ...
            if (packet.hasProtocol(Protocol.TCP)) {
                ...
                JSONOBject obj = new JSONOBject();
                obj.put("Desitnation", destination);
                // set other properties
                arr.add(obj);
                ...
            }
            // same for else if block
            ...
        }
    ...
}
```